# Populating a CLOB Collection Using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, oracle, collections, apex, oracle-apex-5

Kindly, How I can Populating a CLOB value greater than 32K into a Collection Using JavaScript dynamic action.

Note: I am using Apex version: 20.2

Thanks ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.stinolez.com/2020/07/03/clob-in-apex-rich-text-editor/

```js
  // Run the Ajax Callback process
  var p = apex.server.process('GET_CLOB', {
    pageItems:['P1_ID_COLUMN']
  }, {
    dataType: 'html'
  });
  // When the process is done, set the value to the page item
  p.done(function(data) {
    apex.item('P1_CLOB_COLUMN').setValue(data);
  });
```